# How can I get this value from a JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, gettext, jfilechooser

I want to know if there's a way to get the text the user writes in a `JFileChooser` after pressing "accept" (I removed the confirm and cancel buttons) like a text field (`.getText()`).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcNaH.png)

Comment: Are you trying to get the file name?

Comment: No, I am trying to get the text you write there, the file name only works if I select a file in the File Chooser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example I wrote:

```
JFileChooser x=new JFileChooser();
int returnVal=x.showOpenDialog(this);
File file=x.getSelectedFile();
System.out.println(file.getName());
```

Even though the file isn't an actual file it would still print out what is in the box when you call `file.getName()`. When I typed a random string of characters it returned the string of characters even though it's not a file.